# Can the expression 'keep the party going' be used in a figurative way in English?

Tags: phrase-request

I seek to translate the Russian expression 'требовать продолжения банкета' which could be literally translated as "demand the continuation of a banquet". 'Banquet' in the phrase stands for some fun, enjoyable (albeit harmful or irresponsible, perhaps) activity so it means to seek to keep that sort of activity going on, even when it's wiser to cut it out. In English, can I say, instead, "demand the party to go on"? I know there's an expression 'the party is over' where 'party' means something similar to what 'banquet' means in the Russian expression. So, I suppose, you can turn it around to convey what I want to convey, can't you? Would it be idiomatic? If not, what would you recommend instead?

Comment: There are probably *lots* of "idiomatic" alternatives. *Don't stop the carnival!* comes to mind.

Comment: [*Quit **raining on](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22quit+raining+on%22+) our parade**!* *Don't be a **party-pooper**!* Depending on context.

Comment: Keep the party alive.  Party on! Party like there's no tomorrow!

Comment: Party hardy! (using "hardy" as an adverb).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comments section is a bit surprising because it's offering various alternatives to your original proposal.

> "keep the party going"

The phrase has a million hits on Google and forty eight million hits on Bing.  It's certainly idiomatic, if by that we mean "commonplace" and "well understood".

> Can it be used in a figurative way

Sure. Even if it's not a literal banquet, you could say it.

> Is this a good translation for "demand the continuation of a banquet"?

Without being fluent in Russian, I cannot say for sure...

"keep the party going" sounds light-hearted, fun, and brings to mind a "party". You probably wouldn't say *demand* or *require* in English. Those are harsh/strict types of words. If требовать also means "to call for, to want, to desire, to need", as dictionaries indicate, those could fit better.